# xmlHttpRequest post method giving junk values

Tags: php, post, xmlhttprequest

> Sending a post request and a PHP file to write it in a file, for testing i just used 
>   "dummy text" to send a message

```
//FILE - SSE.html
// xmlhttprequest post

//function.................................................

function loadXMLDoc(){    
var xmlhttp;    
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){       
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();      
console.log("request made");  
}     
else      
{     
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");      
}   
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){   
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){      

console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
}   
 }   

xmlhttp.open("POST","writeToFile.php",true);    
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","text/plain;charset=UTF-8");   
xmlhttp.send("dummy text");   
}

// html body.................................................
<form>
<textarea name="q" onKeyUp="loadXMLDoc()" id="ta1" cols=40 rows=10></textarea>
</form>
<textarea id="ta2" cols=40 rows=10></textarea>

//PHP file.......

<?php 


$clientData=$_POST["q"];  

$File = "WrittenByPHP.txt";   
$Handle = fopen($File, w');    
$Data = $clientData;   
fwrite($Handle, $Data);   
fclose($Handle);   ?>
```

> RESULT in console............some junk
>   values..............................
>
> request made SSE.html:46 
>   ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: q in
>   C:\wampnew\www\RD\writeToFile.php on line *4* Call Stack
>   #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0003252112{main}(  )..\writeToFile.php**:**0
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- Why the above junk code resulted? advance thanks.

Comment: Because, your php file expects a variable named `q` sent by the form. Also replace `$Handle = fopen($File, w');` with `$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');`

Comment: Because your php code has printed `Notice` that says clearly that you try to get element of array with the key `q` that is undefined (in another words, does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

Check if `isset()` and exit the script:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["q"])){

        $clientData = $_POST["q"]; 
        $File = "WrittenByPHP.txt";
        $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');    
        $Data = $clientData;   
        fwrite($Handle, $Data);   
        fclose($Handle);
        die;
    }
?>
```

You should sent the `q` parameter in post.

```
var params = "q="+document.getElementById('ta1').value;
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

form:

```
<form>
   <textarea name="q" onKeyUp="loadXMLDoc()" id="ta1" cols=40 rows=10></textarea>
</form>
```

This will submit on every `onKeyUp`, you should change it to `onblur`

Comment: junk code gone.. thanks.. but value not captured... 
q given as parameter as you said

xmlhttp.send("q=dummy text");

Comment: You have to add all my javascript.